# ViewPager not shown after setting layout_weight="1"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have a layout as below

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/slide_pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:visibility="visible" >
            < .. views />
        </RelativeLayout>  </LinearLayout>
```

When I am setting the height of `RelativeLayout` footer to say 200dp , I see the `ViewPager` .If the footer is 'wrap_content' the `ViePager` is fully disappeared. I tried setting weight of `ViewPager` to 1 but of no use . I want the footer to be `wrap_content`. and `ViewPager` to occupy the remaining space.

thank you.

The issue is same even after setting `layout_height` to wrap_content.

Comment: You don't need to set width to 0 dp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that we have to supply the weight to child layouts according to its requirement. So I set weight for viewpager to .75 and to remaining layout to .25 and now the view pager will be displayed to 3/4th of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/slide_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:visibility="visible" >
            < .. views />
        </RelativeLayout>  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If in a vertical LinearLayout, you set the width to 0dp, then it is not going to shown. Also happens in a horizontal LinearLayout and 0dp of height.

Just change the width to wrap_content (or whatever else).